# Cannot connect to the database in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, scala

Terminal shows you are connected to database. While sending request from Postman it shows:

> Cannot connect to database [default].

I have tried different solutions provided in Stack Overflow but it still doesn't work.

What I have done:

```
db{
107  default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
108  default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/student"
109  default.user=postgres
110  default.password=root
```

And this is what I have done in Terminal is:

```
createdb -h localhost -p 5432
postgres student password root
```

Comment: Please add come codes by which others can identify the problem. First Aid : Check whether you have connected to correct database, username, password.

Comment: I have included everything I have done.Can you please help me now.

Comment: initially `postgres` does not have password for the user `postgres` try giving password to the user `postgres` and then try it. BTW which programming language you are using?

Comment: I am not familiar to that. But try what I said. As Scala seems to be part of java, and I got same issues in java what you are facing now. I think that might help.

Comment: When you want to connect to a local postgres database at the default port you can omit host and port. But you should specify user if the login doesn't correspond to the database user: `createdb -Upostgres student`.

Comment: @macmoonshine I have tried this also but still it doesnot work.

Comment: "still it doesnot work" is no useful statement. The quality of answers is proportional to the quality of the corresponding question.

Comment: _"I have tried different solutions provided in Stack Overflow but it still doesn't work."_ - edit your post and add links to the Stack Overflow answers you found, and for each of them, give the result you got from them. In detail.

Comment: Each time I tried different thinks I go the same error:Cannot connect to database [default].

Comment: can you connect to the database through the psql client? if yes, make sure you have the correct user/pass on the configuration. Are you using Play+slick ?

Answer (score 1):

When I get some kind of PostgreSQL connection error the

1. first step I take is to test if `psql' works by using the following command

   ```
   $ psql -d mypgdatabase -U mypguser
   ```
2. If this doesn't give us a clue then the second step is to see if `pg_hba.conf' file has correct permission for our user, for example it should contain a like like this

   ```
   local   all         all                               trust
   ```

   After editing this file don't forget to reload postgresql service by issuing the following command

   ```
   $ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql reload
   ```

   Now try again step 1.

This is all beautifully documented in Debian PostgreSQL wiki page here https://wiki.debian.org/PostgreSql

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
postgres=# sudo -u postgres psql postgres

postgres-# \password postgres

Enter new password: 

Enter it again:
```

In my case password is root as I have keep my default password as root.